# Classy Dojo - Internal method calls

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am a total beginner at dojo and am trying to move some of my interface code into a class just to keep the methods out of my main file.

My problem - I am unable to use internal class functions as part of other functions.

After I create an interface object in an external file as shown, I am able to sucessfully:

```
appInterface = new (interface)
appInterface.showGraphWindow()
appInterface.hideGraphWindow()
```

However I am unable to work out how to use these functions inside of the toggleGraphWindow function. (Due to context ?)

If I attempt to call:

```
 on(registry.byId("graphBtn"),"click", appInterface.toggleGraphWindow);
```

It crashes on the line:

```
  this.showGraphWindow()
```

or

```
this.hideGraphWindow()
```

With: "Undefined is a not a function"

**How do I code the toggleGraphWindow function**?

*Iterface.js*

```
 define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/on",
    "dijit/registry"
      ], 
  function(
    declare,
    on,
    registry
    ){
    return declare (null, {
        hideGraphWindow : function () {
            dijit.byId("graphWindowMain").domNode.style.display = 'none';  
            dijit.byId("applicationWindow").resize();   
        },
        showGraphWindow : function () { 
            dijit.byId("graphWindowMain").domNode.style.display = 'block';  
            dijit.byId("applicationWindow").resize();
        },
        toggleGraphWindow : function (){
                if (dijit.byId("graphBtn").checked ==  true)
                    {this.showGraphWindow()}
                else 
                    {this.hideGraphWindow()}
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess the real question here might be related to *what's calling toggleGraphWindow*?  You're not showing whatever code is calling it.  `hitch` in the way you are using it here is doing absolutely nothing in two senses - 1, `hitch` returns a function, so you're generating a function and never calling it, and 2, if you've got a context problem somewhere, calling `hitch` here is too late to solve it because `this` is already wrong - which goes back to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you both, you were indeed correct Ken, I had read this similar post a lot of times, and somehow didnt understand the answer within:

[Calling object methods internally in dojo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188816/calling-object-methods-internally-in-dojo)

After reading what you have posted, I have somehow understood the answer linked above and now understand what my problem was! Thanks to all.

I fixed it by altering my code in the main application as follows:

```
var appInterface = new Interface();
on(registry.byId("graphBtn"),"click", appInterface.toggleGraphWindow);
```

changed to:

```
var appInterface = new Interface();
var graphToggle = dojo.hitch(appInterface, "toggleGraphWindow");
on(registry.byId("graphBtn"),"click", graphToggle);
```

I believe the reason for the error, was that the "this" object at runtime, was actually the "graphBtn" instead of the appInterface.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with

```
    toggleGraphWindow : function (){
            if (dijit.byId("graphBtn").checked ==  true) {
                this.showGraphWindow();
            }
            else {
                this.hideGraphWindow();
            }
    }
```

?

Comment: I am attempting to call it in the main application:

 var appInterface = new Interface();
appInterface.hideGraphWindow();
appInterface.toggleGraphWindow();

I originally had it as shown by Jan, but my code errors on 'this.showGraphWindow line (within the toggle function) with "undefined is not a function"